# Terraform returns "Unsupported service namespace, resource type or scalable dimension" when I attach an auto-scaling group to an ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, terraform

In my terraform code, I am trying to attach an auto-scaling group to my ECS Service using `aws_autoscaling_target`.

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "service_app_asg_target" {
  resource_id = "${aws_ecs_service.service_app.arn}"
  min_capacity = 2
  max_capacity = 6
  role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_autoscale_role.arn}"
}
```

When I apply this, amazon gives me the error

> Unsupported service namespace, resource type or scalable dimension

What's wrong with my attachment?

Answer (score 7):

You didn't correctly format the *resource_id* in your *aws_appautoscaling_target*. It needs to be in the format **service/*clusterName*/*serviceName***, and terraform will not format it for you. Try:

```
resource_id = "service/${aws_ecs_cluster.MY_CLUSTER.name}/${aws_ecs_service.MY_SERVICE.name}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CloudFormation version in case someone needs it.
Node the cluster and the service are text not references

```
   ScalableTarget:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    Properties:
      RoleARN: !GetAtt AutoScalingRole.Arn
      ResourceId: service/ECSCluster/ECSService
```